# Time of individual calls in history, if *same* number consecutively

Tags: samsung, call-history

Samsung Galaxy S10, Andorid 11, OneUI 3.1

To obtain time and number of recent calls, I got to the phone app, tap "recent" on the bottom, and see a list of incoming and outgoing calls with phone number and time. However, if it was the same phone number several times consecutively, it shows only the last time, and the number of calls in brackets: "phone_number (3) 12:34".

Is there a way to get a list of *all* calls *individually* (for *all* numbers, even if several times the *same* number consecutively).

(I know I can tap a line, hit "i", and see the whole list of calls for *only this* number.)

I prefer a native solution, but if a 3rd party app should be necessary, I prefer clean (as few rights as possible, no advertising, possibly open source) over "for free".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free software [Simple Dialer](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.simplemobiletools.dialer/) has a relevant setting. As of now, the text of the setting is this:

"Group subsequent calls with the same number at the call log"

Disable the setting. That would list each call as a separate entry. Note that reverse chronological order of all the calls would not be affected. So if you had made a call to X at 01:00, then to Y at 02:00, then to Z at 03:00, and then X again at 04:00, it would show up as expected:

- X at 04:00
- Z at 03:00
- Y at 02:00
- X at 01:00